# Access Linux MySQLdb using python module

Tags: python, linux, mysql-python

I see that MySQLdb is present in /opt/xxx/python2.6/site-    packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/* path in my server.

```
the default paths 
/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6    
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

Under `/usr/lib64/mysql/*`, I see the below mentioned .so files.

```
    drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 May  2 14:40 .
    dr-xr-xr-x. 67 root root   57344 May  2 14:56 ..
    -rwxr-xr-x   2 root root 9700193 Feb  1 19:01 libmsql.lib
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      24 May  2 13:17 libmysqlclient ->    libmysqlclient.so.20.2.0
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      24 Mar 25 13:12 libmysqlclient.so.20 -> libmysqlclient.so.20.2.0
    -rwxr-xr-x   2 root root 9700193 Feb  1 19:01 libmysqlclient.so.20.2.0
    drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Mar 25 13:13 mecab
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      24 May  2 13:17 mysqlclient ->     libmysqlclient.so.20.2.0
```

Im trying to run my script from /root where in its taking the default paths.    Im returning with the below error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
    File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0- 1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python- 1.2.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
    ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody correct me and help in fixing this issue. Should I set any environmental variables so that the module can be imported.

Comment: Did you read the traceback?

Comment: I understand the issue with libmysqlclient_r.so.16. But how should I correct it.

Comment: Install the missing library.

Comment: Should I install complete package "MySQL" or any way to download only particular lib files.

Comment: That's between you and your distro.

Comment: Check whether you have `libmysqlclient_r` really on system , use `locate libmysqlclient_r`.